# Conditional transpose of rows to columns

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, transpose

I have the following table with around 500 rows that I need to transpose into columns:

```
    A  B
   A1 B1
   A2 B2
   A3 B3
```

The result I'm trying to get is

```
A  B  C  D  E  F
A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but the normal transpose doesn't give me the desired result. As you can see from my initial question I need all the data from 2 rows to be inserted on one row following a specific order. Basically I need a normal transpose of cell A and between A1 and A2 I need to have B1 and so on and forth(with a normal transpose B1 would end up below A1).

Answer (score 0):

Because the results are to be the interleaving of two columns I think not a duplicate of the OP indicated (at one time). Assuming `A1` is in cell A2 (i.e. `A` and `B` are column labels) I suggest in C2 and copied across to suit:

```
=IF(ISODD(COLUMN()),OFFSET($A1,COLUMN()/2,0),OFFSET($A1,(COLUMN()/2)-1,1))
```

Comment: In the meanwhile I managed it using the following formula
'=INDEX(Range,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS(Range)),MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS(Range),COLUMNS(Range))+1)` 

But your formula works like a charm as well. Thank you